# How are atoms formes by electromagnetic waves that a specific frequency?

Tags: cold-atoms

I came up something like this- Every piece of matter has a resonancefrequency or series of frequenciesbecause all matter is made up of atoms. Atoms are formed by electromagnetic waves that have a specific frequency. When these atoms form a larger piece of matter, thefrequency of the electromagnetic waves is the frequency of that matter.

What Are the Earth's Harmonic Resonate Frequencies? | Sciencing
 Wait what?...Atoms are formes by electromagnetic waves that a specific frequency?Can you explain how?

Here is the link-https://sciencing.com/earths-harmonic-resonate-frequencies-8600773.html

Comment: This site is not for sharing personal theories, but rather for asking questions about mainstream physics. In general, you can expect questions with personal theories to get closed.

Comment: This is not personal theory, i found it in sciencing

Comment: Can you post the link to where you read this?

Comment: Since you said “I came up with something like this”, I assumed it was your personal theory. In any case, it isn’t mainstream physics.

Comment: Yeah sure, here-https://sciencing.com/earths-harmonic-resonate-frequencies-8600773.html

Comment: @G.Smith sorry, i would not do the mistake again

Comment: I recommend that you stop reading anything on the website "sciencing.com".

Comment: Ok, there is always a threat to get wrong information and you donot know from where

Comment: Yes, that’s unfortunately a problem! Good luck!

Comment: You can learn a lot from this site as long as you only pay attention to answers by people with high reputation scores. Of course, people with low scores can post good answers too, and people with high scores can post bad answers. But in general a high reputation is earned by being more right than wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the wave nature of quantum (subatomic) particles. The duality principle of quantum physics tells us that the quantum particles are both a wave and a particle at the same time. When a particle is observed/measured (or generally interacted with) its wave function (possibilities of the particle) collapses into a definite particle, meaning that in a macro system each individual particle should not be regarded as a wave.
You can look into the double slit experiment to get a better grasp of what is the duality and in which cases is it applicable.

Comment: Can you plz explain it further

Comment: An electron is a wave, subatomic particles making an atom is a wave, but the atom itself is not. We are saying it is a wave only because we know that they interfene with each other just like waves and we can observe the interference patter in an experiment (as I said look up double slit experiment, this topic is covered in youtube a lot, so you can just watch a video demonstrating it).

Comment: You mean that electrons act like wave, making an atom a wave. I meant that atom is formed(made) by em wave.how?

Answer (score 1):

Atoms are *not* formed by electromagnetic waves. They are formed from positively charged nuclei and negatively charged electrons, held together by electrostatic attraction between opposite charges. The electric field inside an atom sitting in its ground state is not “waving”. Atoms do emit or absorb electromagnetic waves of particular frequencies when they transition between different possible energy states, but these waves are not trapped inside the atom and play no role in holding it together.